# Finding the Outline Level of a Office 2010 Word Document using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word, ms-office

I'm creating a VBA macro that will validate a submitted document, but I can't seem to find a way to check for the Outline Level of the document as a whole. What I need is a way to tell the outline level selected in the Outlining Ribbon, 1-9 or All Levels.

Answer (score 3):

The setting you are after is an application setting which is not stored in the file.

You can set a specific level using the following VBA code:

```
ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Type = wdOutlineView
ActiveWindow.View.ShowHeading 6
```

Comment: I need a getter, anywhere in the object model. Application level works.

Comment: @Donnie H: As far as I know, this setting is neither persisted, nor is it possible to retrieve the current value using the object model. The setting will be initialized to "show level 9" when you start Word. The rest depends on what the user is selecting.

Answer (score 0):

The [.OutlineLevel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa173290%28office.11%29.aspx) property of a Word document can apply to the Paragraph, ParagraphFormat or Paragraphs Collection objects. It is an enumeration that can take the values wdOutlineLevel1 - 9, or wdOutlineLevelBodyText.

To find the OutlineLevel of the first paragraph in the document, use:

```
Dim currOutlineLevel

With ActiveDocument
  currOutlineLevel = .Paragraphs(1).OutlineLevel
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that calling Paragraphs(x).OutlineLevel errors if called with the active doc in Outline view which makes iterating an Word outline for export rather a bore. You have to toggle the view (which also doesn't appear to be directly scriptable) then toggle back. Hope that saves someone else wasting time...